# How to filter chromeosdevices by org unit?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I am working with the Google Admin SDK Directory API in managing domain Chromebooks. I am reviewing the chromeosdevices.list method, in hopes of reducing the number of returned device resources by filtering for a specific OU either by OrgUnitPath or by OrgUnitId. The documentation hints that this may be possible through use of the query parameter:

> query string  Search string in the format given at View device information and organizational units.

Using the [tool available with the documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/chromeosdevices/list#try-it) I am able to exercise query parameters such as `status:deprovisioned` but am unable to limit by OU placement.

Is it possible with the current Directory API to get a list of chromeosdevice resources for a specific OU? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using gShell with this command:

```
Get-GAChromeosdevice -All | where {$_.OrgUnitPath -like "*[organisation]"}
```

Thing is you will be checking all devices.
Maby this will be an option in the next version of the Directory API

Answer (score 0):

I have a function that does this.  Look at "whereMyChromiesAt()" on the following site.

https://github.com/stephengale801/random-GAS-scripts/blob/e8f9617bf24e3a2ec2bf11f04960e1f1d9bf96f2/Sync-OU-to-Group/ImportUsers.gs

Sorry I couldn't type it out, in on my phone ATM.

Comment: Thank you for the script, but that's actually what I do now. We have a lot of devices, and just exporting all of them actually takes almost two minutes. I'm hoping I can shrink that down by only getting specific OUs in a call.

Comment: I've seen one or two other scripts using the `query:{"orgUnitPath":"/path"}` but when I attempted to use it in my script - it didn't work as expected.